# Button array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, button, for-loop

I have this code

```
Button[] ButtonArray = { btn1, btn2, btn3 };
for (int i = 0; i >= 3; i++)
{
     ButtonArray[i].Text = loadData[i];
}
```

What I try to do is that in the buttons `btn1`, `btn2` and `btn3` loads the data from `loadData` array in its text property

When running the program it doesn't load anything.

Comment: _I wrote this program and it doesn't work._ [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put `i >= 3` instead of `i <= 3`. Flip it and you should be good.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't worked: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: It should be `i < 3` not `i <= 3` since array has 3 item.

Comment: @geekth How about `i < loadData.Length`